# Argotic Syndication framework

Tags: .net-3.5, rss, argotic

Is it me or is the documentation for the argotic framework API  impossible to find..?

The source is available so surely the documented API should be ..

Anybody know where this is?

Thanks alot,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay just download the source and documentation from the link - entire API documented in HELP file